# Is the resolution of the identity 'unique'?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I want to know how many ways the identity operator $I$ on a (finite) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ can be written as sum of outer products of states like $|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$.

For example, $$I=\sum_i |u_i\rangle\langle u_i|,$$ where $\{|u_i\rangle\}_i$ is any orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$.

But also, if $\mu$ is the Haar measure over $\mathcal{H}$, then I believe that
$$I=\int |x\rangle\langle x| d\mu(x) $$ is also correct?

My question is whether there are any other ways to write the identity operator as a sum of outer products. If $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H_1}\oplus \mathcal{H_2}$ we can write the identity in the first form on $\mathcal{H_1}$ and in the second on $\mathcal{H_2}$. But is there another way?

I tried to find another 'discrete' sum but one where the vectors weren't orthonormal, but everything I tried failed. After reading other stack exchange questions I found out that these things are called 'resolutions of the identity', but I couldn't work out the answer to the above question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your integral. For $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{R}$, we could say $|x\rangle \langle x|$ is the $1\times 1$ matrix $[x^2]$, and $\int_{\Bbb R}[x^2]\,\mathrm{d}x$ certainly doesn't converge. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If you mean the Haar measure over the unit sphere in $\mathcal{H}$, then the integral is correct. I think that's what Mims means.

Comment: Let $n=\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})$ and let $\{\lvert u_1\rangle,\dots,\lvert u_n\rangle\}\subset\mathcal{H}$ be any collection of vectors. It holds that $\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert u_i\rangle\langle u_i\rvert = I$ if and only if $\{\lvert u_1\rangle,\dots,\lvert u_n\rangle\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that discusses this (for the discrete case): "A complete classification of quantum ensembles having a given density matrix". There they show many different ways to write the identity matrix. For example, you can write it as the outer product of $\{1,0\}$, $\{1/2, \sqrt{3}/2\}$, $\{1/2, -\sqrt{3}/2\}$ (with a normalisation factor).